# How can I make -p the default for git stash show?

Tags: git

When I show a git stash with `git stash show`, I get a diffstat. `git stash show -p` gives me the stash as a patch, which is much more useful for seeing what's in there.

I'm not really keen on having an alias like `git config --global alias.sts 'stash show -p'`, as I never remember what aliases I have — I'd rather have `git stash show` default to displaying as a patch.

Is there a way to make -p the default, so just typing `git stash show` does the right thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm afraid that's not possible. Under the hood, `git stash show` actually executes `git diff`. It is passed `--stat` as the default.

Answer (score 3):

Use git aliases and retrain your muscle memory.

You'll need to edit your `~/.gitconfig` file to do this.

If you already have aliases you'll see a line that looks like this in `~/.gitconfig`:

`[alias]`

If you do not, you need to add such a line.

Immediately after the line containing only `[alias]` you need to add the following line:

`sp = stash show -p`

Now executing `git sp` from your command line will show the result of `git stash show -p`

Season to taste.